# How to Stop scroll event from affecting other page in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have a browse feature that uses infinite scroll to load more data on the page. It works fine; however, when I route to a different page, that page also scroll down automatically.

Is there a way to kill the scroll event when changing route or during unmount?

So far I tried these ways:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');

$(window).bind('touchmove',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

The only lacking part is to stop the scroll event when changing routes / page. Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount) lifecycle method to unbind all handlers

Comment: Actually I added the unbind and the `touchmove` on `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` but still the same result. That is what got me confused :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use from listeners in `reactjs` like this :

```
 componentDidMount = ()=> {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);

      };

      componentWillUnmount = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);

      };
      handleResize = (e) => {
        const W = window.innerWidth;
        this.setState({windowWidth: W});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the issue, the issue occurs when I go on to another page while the previous page is still loading or subscribing data. Now I am trying to find a way on how to cut subscription process.